# OSX find a file with (1) in its name

Tags: find

I have tried lots of variants of find and I can't seem to figure out which one to use to find files with names like

`product (1).php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses have no special meaning in the filename matching pattern used by `find`, so you can just use:

```
  find name_of_folder -type f -name '*(1)*'
```

Use quotes as usual to protect the asterisks from being expanded by the shell.